# Cannot open Google Maps in an iOS Application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps, viewdidload

I'm trying to launch Google Maps iOS Application in my Application by doing this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    self.title                  =   @"Google Map";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                @"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
}
```

However, the app does not launch Google Maps iOS at all. I do have Google Maps iOS installed.

What I am missing over here?

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work when you type that same URL into Safari's address bar?

Comment: No it does not work in Safari's address bar. I am following the tutorial at [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

Comment: That's interesting, pasting the URL into Safari is working fine for me. Are you possibly confusing the iOS 5 maps app with the official Google Maps iOS app? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CFYQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fgoogle-maps%2Fid585027354%3Fmt%3D8&ei=80vsUJ7DE6XZigLpvYHwBg&usg=AFQjCNEMo8V21rKG52EDBal5WJ0CoFLoHQ&sig2=NGWtZnlNmkDI9Ivt26sikQ&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.cGE

Comment: i tried but not working please look at [here](http://cl.ly/M1iI) for what I have tried

Comment: You'll have to do it on your device where the app is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = COORDINATE;

// Open Google Maps application
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {

    NSString *daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g,%g",coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];

    NSString *urlString = nil;

    BOOL showQuery = YES;
    if (showQuery) {
        // Query
        urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?q=%@",daddr];
    } else {
        // Directions
        urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=%@", daddr];
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include comgooglemaps url scheme to your project Info.plist. I recommend checking out [Localide](https://github.com/davoda/Localide). It helps you open Google Maps, Waze, Apple Maps, Transit App, Citymapper, and Navigon very easily.